# Generate playlist from files recursive

Tags: php, batch-file

I have multiple folders with small videos and i need to make a rss feed from them.
Structure of the files is like this:

MainFolder ->

```
   -> File.Summer-> file.summer.p01f1.mp4, file.summer.p01f2.mp4......,file.summer.p02f1.mp4 ,file.summer.p02f2.mp4.... and so on.

   -> File.Winter-> file.winter.p01f1.mp4, file.winter.p01f2.mp4......,file.winter.p02f1.mp4,file.winter.p02f2.mp4.... and so on.
```

What i need is a solution to generate those rss creating a feed like file.summer.p01.rss and the content is all the files containing p01f1, p01f2 then next to file.summer.p02.rss. In all the folders in the path.

I found a solution which makes a single rss with all the files in the folder but i need the rss to be split in parts matching the file names.
It can be a windows bat or a php script.
Thank you.

this is the script i have now:

```
$list="file.summer";  
$part="01";  
$ser_dir = 'c:\www\php\movs\\'.$list;  
$rss_head = '<rss version="2.0">';  
$movs_path="../php/movs/";  
$iosser = "/iosser/";  
$file_out = $ser_dir."\\".$list.".p".$part.".rss";  

$xml = $rss_head. "\n";  
$xml .="<channel>"."\n";
 foreach (glob($ser_dir."\*.p".$part."*.srt" ,GLOB_NOSORT) as $filename) {  
 $xml .="<item>". "\n";  
     $xml .= "<title>".basename($filename, ".srt")."</title>\n";  
     $filename=basename($filename);
     $xml .= "<image>".$movs_path.$list."/".substr($filename, 0,-7).".jpg</image>\n";  
     $xml .= '<source file="'.$iosser.$list."/".basename($filename,".srt").'.mov"/>'."\n";
     $xml .="</item>". "\n";  
 }  

$xml .="</channel>"."\n";  

$xml .= "</rss>";  

file_put_contents($file_out,$xml);  
echo $list ."\n";  
echo $part;
```

Comment: Well, if you already have a working solution that is close, then why not modify it to your requirements instead of asking here for a solution from scratch?

Comment: with all the respect but if i knew how to do that, i wouldn't post the question here. That script is from this site but is not what i need, somebody told me is better to do a new script than modify one which was created for a specific task . Thank you

Comment: Well you see, there are hundreds of existing solutions, all to be found on google. You do not say why you cannot adapt the one you have or one of all those out there to your needs (you give no details), yet you ask here that someone creates a solution for you for free. That is not really fair...

Comment: you have right, i can't paste the script i found from this site it says is to long